# How can I avoid ThresholdException while fetching data using REST query

Tags: 2010, rest, sharepoint-list

I have a list in SP 2010 from which a Java program fetches data using a REST query.

```
http://sharepointfarm/sites/testsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/OurList?$select=Id,Title
```

The XML response currently shows the below error, even after using a `select` query.

```
<message>
The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator.
</message>
<type>Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException</type>
```

[This article](http://www.fkylewright.com/archives/1521) mentions the select parameter does not restrict the ViewFields on the server.

Is there any way out to fetch the data into Java? Can we split the query to avoid the ThresholdException?

We need to fetch all records in the list.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Via Central Administration: Manage web applications / Select the web application, then from the drop down list 'General Settings' select 'Resource Throttling' / change the value of 'List View Lookup Threshold'

Or via PowerShell:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://YourSharePointSite
$wa.MaxQueryLookupFields = 20
$wa.Update()
```

Comment: my site is on a shared farm; I cannot afford to modify the Threshold as it can affect performance.

Comment: In the you mentioned, In Final Outcome "So if the totality of your list columns exceeds the lookup column threshold, there is no way to retrieve any subset of those columns using listdata.svc, outside of the large query window configured on your farm"